# React: Como posso enviar dados para o this.state

Tags: ionic, react, firebase

Boa noite, estou iniciando no react e tenho a seguinte linha:

class NameList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

```
    this.state = {
        clientes: []
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.getUserData();
}


getUserData = () => {
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('/');
    ref.on('value', snapshot => {
        const state = snapshot.val();
        this.setState(state);
        console.log(state);
    });
    console.log("Dados Recebidos !")
};

render() {
    const { clientes } = this.state;
    return(
        <IonList>
        {clientes.map((item,index) => 
        <IonItem key={index}> 
        <IonLabel>
        <p>Nome:</p>
        <h2>{item.Name}</h2>
        <p>Horário:</p>
        <h2>{item.Horario}</h2>
        </IonLabel>
        <IonLabel></IonLabel>
        <IonLabel>
        <IonButton color="success"><IonIcon icon={checkmark} /></IonButton>
        <IonButton color="danger"><IonIcon icon={trash} /></IonButton>
        </IonLabel>
        </IonItem>
        )}
    </IonList>

    );
}
```

}

O que não estou conseguindo é somente preencher o **state** que tem o array de clientes, para redenrizar uma lista. Está tudo funcional, os dados estao vindo porém o **{clientes} = this.state** não é preenchido com eles.

Comment: O que tem no seu `snapshot.val()`?

Comment: vem os dados do firebase, exatamente assim: clientes: [{nome: 'Teste', horario: 'teste'}]

Comment: Se você usar outro nome de variável pra guardar isso, funciona? (ex: `const newState = await ...` e depois `this.setState(newState)`) Porque se o valor realmente estiver certo, eu não vejo problemas além de você estar criando uma variável com o mesmo nome do `state`.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui, logo mais darei retorno, mesmo assim obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar desta forma:

```
getUserData = () => {
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('/');
    ref.on('value', snapshot => {
        const {clientes} = snapshot.val();
        this.setState({clientes: clientes}); // ou this.setState({clientes})
        console.log(clientes);
    });
    console.log("Dados Recebidos !")
};
```

Observe se o `console.log(clientes)` retorna :  `[{nome: 'Teste', horario: 'teste'}]` ,
caso não, sua função `getUserData` não está recebendo os dados corretamente.